# AWS Datadog integration issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, datadog, apm, aws-roles

I have created AWS Role/Policies but when I am trying to integrate AWS with Datadog APM I entered my AWS account details and role, and I see:

> Access denied. See https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_web_services/

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're not using the AWS Account ID from Datadog.

> For Account ID, enter 464622532012 (Datadog’s account ID). This means that you are granting Datadog read only access to your AWS data.

Also make sure you're not requiring MFA.

**References:**

[Datadog AWS Integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_web_services/?tab=roledelegation)

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be this issue only.